# Meteor : Retrieve value in Meteor.call which calls a server method having promise

Tags: node.js, meteor, meteor-methods

I have an internally maintained npm package `myNpmPackage` which exports a function (for e.g. `fnTestMicroSerConn` ) as below:

```
const rp = require('request-promise-native')

exports.fnTestMicroSerConn = function () {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var options = {
      method: 'GET',
      uri : "http://example.net", 
      resolveWithFullResponse: true,
    }
    rp(options)
      .then(function (response) {
        if (response.statusCode !== 200){
          console.error("http not 200 but : ",response.statusCode)
          resolve(false)
        } else  {
          console.info("connected successfully : "+response.body)
          resolve(response)
        }
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
          console.error("Error in establishing connectivity  : ",err)
          resolve(false)
      })
    })
}
```

I then need to call the above exported function from a Meteor method like so:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import myNpmPackage from 'myNpmPackage';

Meteor.methods({   
 foo: function () {
   myNpmPackage.fnTestMicroSerConn().then(function (response){
     console.log(" My response: ",response.body);
    return(response.body)
   })
 }
});
```

`console.log(" My response: ",response.body);` gets executed successfully and I can see the expected value in **the server console log**. So till here it's good.

However, now I want to pass the value of `response.body` to the **client side**. In short, when I do below on the client :

```
Meteor.call("foo", function (err, response) {
      console.log("calling foo");
      if(!err){
        console.log("response : ",response);
      } else {
        console.log("err : ",err);
      }
    })
```

Unfortunately, currently I am getting `undefined` on the client for `console.log("response : ",response);`

Note: I am using the Meteor Promise package from [here](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/promise)

Let me know if any more details are needed or any thing is unclear. I am very new to the *Promise* style of coding, hence, this can sound as a noob question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor methods called from clients by `Meteor.call` run synchronously to prevent clients from pending, even if a callback is supplied.

Your `foo` method does not wait for that promise inside. It runs past `fnTestMicroSerConn()` call  without hesitation and ends up with no more statement to execute, returning `undefined` as a result. By the time the promise resolved and logged the expected message on the server console, the method had been exited.

To get resolved/rejected result of that promise, you can return the promise from the method to the caller, and the client would be able to respond to the promise.

```
Meteor.methods({   
 foo: function () {
   return myNpmPackage.fnTestMicroSerConn();
 }
});

Meteor.call("foo")
  .then( response => console.log("My response: ", response.body) )
  .catch( err => console.log("err : ",err) );
```

Meteor methods is powerful. The [API documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html) of methods contains much information and is worth mastery.